# Boolean operator code not working for me in python, trying to create a "true - true" response but it is not working

Tags: python, boolean

I am trying to write an expression that prints a statement if both the variables are  True

I chose the "and" Boolean operator as it requires both statements to be true but the code fails my tests

Here is my code:

write an expression that prints "You must be rich!" if the variables young and famous are both true

```
young = (input() == 'True')

famous = (input() == 'True')

if (young == 'True') and (famous == 'True'):
    print('You must be rich!')
else:
    print('There is always the lottery...')
```

Comment: What input do you expect your users to supply?

Comment: `True != "True"`

Answer (score 2):

`young` and `famous` will both return `True` (a boolean, not a string) if the input `"True"` is used (without quotes). This is because you're checking if the input is equal to the True string.
Note that the inputs will be case sensitive, so if you input `"true"` it will give a `False` boolean. You can implement the `str.lower()` method to bypass this.

Because this is done, you can just check if `young` and `famous` are both True boolean values by using:

```py
if young and famous:
    print("You must be rich!")
else:
    print("There is always the lottery...")
```